# useState react hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to learn React hooks. But I cannot get the first one to work. It's such a basic app at this point, but if I can't get useState to work, I can't move forward.

```
import React, { useState } from "react-dom"
import './App.css';

function App(props) {
  const [click, setClick] = useState(0);

  const handleChange = e => { 
    console.log(e.target.value)
  }

  const handleClick = e => { 
    console.log(e.target)
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      Value<input type="text" onChange={ handleChange }/>
      <select>
        <option>F to C degrees</option>
        <option>C to F degrees</option>
      </select>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Go</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

That is my app and just so you know all my reacts are the same version

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
```

And the error I get is:

```
TypeError: Object is not a function or its return value is not iterable
App
src/App.js:5
  2 | import './App.css';
  3 | 
  4 | function App(props) {
> 5 |   const [click, setClick] = useState(0);
  6 | 
  7 |   const handleChange = e => { 
  8 |     console.log(e.target.value)
```

Comment: You should create a minimal reproducible example (preferably on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/))

Comment: Looks like you haven't imported useState,..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import React, { useState } from "react"
```

This is the correct import statement

Comment: Yes, thank you. I looked at the code so much I missed that. It was so obvious.

Answer (score 0):

I think `react-dom` does not have `useState`, so change the top of your file to:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react"
import './App.css';

function App(props) {
  const [click, setClick] = useState(0);

  const handleChange = e => { 
    console.log(e.target.value)
  }

  const handleClick = e => { 
    console.log(e.target)
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      Value<input type="text" onChange={ handleChange }/>
      <select>
        <option>F to C degrees</option>
        <option>C to F degrees</option>
      </select>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Go</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import React from "react"

const App = (props)=>{
const [click, setClick] = useState(0);

const handleChange = e => { 
console.log(e.target.value)

 }

 const handleClick = e => { 
 console.log(e.target)
  
}

return (
<div className="App">
  Value<input type="text" onChange={ handleChange }/>
  <select>
    <option>F to C degrees</option>
    <option>C to F degrees</option>
  </select>
  <button onClick={handleClick}>Go</button>
</div>
  );
  } 

 export default App;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but you're expected to explain what the code does, what you changed and why it solves the problem. In this case you're not importing `useState` so the code won't work.